# Elastalert fails importing monotonic from time in module stomp

Tags: python, elasticsearch, python-2.x, elastalert

Looks like since 2020 elastalert fails when it's imported

log says: cannot import monotonic from time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elastalert doesn't pin "stomp" lib version and "stomp" has released a new version which doesn't support python2.

You can just add in your requirements.txt the "stomp" lib pinning the version 4.1.22 or lower.

stomp.py==4.1.22